# Ajax loading directive is not binding and showing on the view in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I created a directive that is working on other states, but at one state it is not working.

directive code is:

(function () {

```
angular.module('rbApp')
    .directive('loading', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace:true,
        template: '<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; position: relative; z-index:999; top: 5%; left: 5%;"><img src="http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/videogallery/ajax-loader.gif" width="150" height="150" /></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$watch('loading', function (val) {
                console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>"+val)

                    if (val)
                        $(element).show();
                    else
                        $(element).hide();

            });
        }
    }
 })
```

})();

on the view i have written

same way as others.

but in this case i can't see the image on this view.

what could be the problem, no error is coming btw.

Comment: can you show more code?And where it is not working?On some specific view?

Comment: can you share the code of controller for view where its not working

Comment: `loading` variable is the only reason for your problem. May be its not getting changed somewhere... can you just share some code where you are setting `loading` variable.

Comment: My view was fetching some data on click of that button that also initiates the loader and that fetching was hanging my browser so nothing was happening, thats why i used the timeout in that case. Its Done,

Answer (score 0):

My view was fetching some data on click of that button that also initiates the loader and that fetching was hanging my browser so nothing was happening, thats why i used the timeout in that case. Its Done, thanks guys!!.